# Fifa 11 Career mode take Virtual Pro when moving clubs

Tags: fifa-11

Just finished my first season in Career mode and was disappointed that all of my job offers at the end of the season are for "Manager" only. The only offer of Player Manager was with my first club.

Does this mean I'm now stuck with my original club (Perth Glory) if I want to continue using my VP?

If I move clubs am I likely to ever get another offer as Player Manager?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you move clubs, you lose your Virtual Pro. He disappears from the game then. (I know, it's kinda stupid.)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to manage your new club for a year and then you will get an option to be a player manager there.

Comment: I've been playing Fifa 11 and 12 almost exclusively playing Career mode and I've never been offered the chance to be a player-manager after leaving my first club.